# PHP image and link convertor function

Tags: php

i am relatively new to PHP and i need a function that converts all URLs to clickable links and any URL that has an image extension (i.e. jpg, png, gif) to an image.

So what i have so far is

```
    function linkandimage($str) {
     $return = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $str);
   return $return;
    }
```

This works find with links, but i haven't gotten a solution for images. Any help would be great,

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, you had half of it. Just add another component to the regex to search for images:

```
function linkandimage($str) {
  $return = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?\.(gif|png|jpe?g))@', '<img src="$1" />', $str);
  $return = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $return);

  return $return;
}
```

Comment: Can i make so images don't convert to links?

Comment: No, the link converts into an image fine, but then the URL within the image (for the src='') is converted into a link. it turns out like this <img src="<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_black">http://www.google.com</a>">